# Magento2 : I want to show user's profile picture in my account

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

**user can upload image when**

1. Register
2. After login, from my account

[image]

Comment: Create New Attribute named "Image" & use file upload. For help http://webkul.com/blog/how-to-upload-image-in-magento2/ & https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule

Comment: @Pawan, did you get a solution?

Comment: @Jsparo30, Yes got the solution, I have created a custom module for that.

Comment: @Pawan, Please If you can share it or answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184272/create-custom-avatar-attribute-on-registration-page

Comment: please check my answer - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294476/magento2-3-how-to-upload-profile-picture-and-show-it-on-my-account-dashboard/294489#294489