# Magento2.3: How to upload profile picture and show it on My Account dashboard?

Tags: magento2.3, css, xml, html, myaccount

We have customized the My Account dashboard with our own design. Now we wanted to implement the profile picture option while the customer do the registration.

After the registration, in My Account dashboard, we want to show that image as in below attachment marked as red.

[image]
How can I do this in Magento 2?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: do you want something like that? https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-customize-my-account-page-extension.html

Comment: @WaqarAli, Please suggest me any free extensions

Comment: you just need profile picture?

Comment: @WaqarAli, Yes, you're right. Once customer upload the profile picture. I want to show the picture at marked place as in question.

Comment: i will answer as soon as possible.. are you aware with Module Development?

Comment: @WaqarAli, Yes, I'm aware with module development.

Comment: ok maybe n two or three hours i will give you an answer

Comment: @WaqarAli, Thank you. For your info, I'm using Magento 2 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Siva Here is your answer

Comment: @WaqarAli, Thank you, I will check the code in my project and let you know.

Comment: Welcome.. Happy Coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created custom module here for **profile picture**

You can try to [download](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-profile-picture) and install module in your `app/code` directory and run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you so much Kishan

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Comment: Is it compatible with magento 2.3.4? @KishanSavaliya

Answer (score 1):

Please try to install below module URL, which have provide to upload your profile pic...

https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar

Comment: I have tried this but its not working. Please suggest alternate one.. If its free extension that would be better

Comment: After installing this module, I'm getting the picture upload option in Account information menu but I can't upload the image. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: have you get any error ?

Comment: I couldn't see any error but still I can't upload the picture.

Comment: can you please check log.

Comment: Checked on log as well and couldn't see error. What could be the problem. I'm using Enterprise Edition. Will that be like compatible issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Your

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/layout/customer_Account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
             <block class="Vednor\Module\Block\CustomAvatar" name="customer_custom" before="customer_account_navigation"   template="Vednor_Module::customavatar.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

In your

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/templates/customeravatar.phtml

```
<div class="main_profile_sidebar_container">
  <div class="profile_sidebar_container">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl() . 'myaccountpages/customavatar'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
      <div class="user-account">
        <div class="avatar">
          <label for="profile_picture">
            <img id="preview" src="<?php echo $avatar['link']; ?>" alt="">
          </label>
          <input id="profile_picture" requried type="file" name="profile_picture" value="<?php echo $avatar['name']; ?>"  />
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your `UpgradeSchema.php`

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

/**
 * Class Upgrade Data
 */
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * Cunstructor
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory  = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Adding Custom Attribute to Magento
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface
     * @param ModuleContextInterface
     * @return null
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet     = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'profile_picture',
            [
                'type'         => 'text',
                'label'        => 'Profile Picture',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order'   => 1000,
                'position'     => 1000,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
        $Attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'profile_picture')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id'   => 1,
                'attribute_group_id' => 1,
                'used_in_forms'      => ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout'],
            ]);

        $Attribute->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

In your Controller to Save Image in Database

```
Vendor/Module/Controller/Index.php

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

/**
 * Class Index
 */
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var String
     */
    const CUSTOM_CUSTOMER_ATTR = 'profile_picture';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerFactory
     */
    private $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context
     * @param CustomerFactory
     * @param Customer
     * @param Session
     * @param \Vendor\Module\\Model\ImageUploader
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        Session $customerSession,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader $imageUploader,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->customerFactory   = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerSession   = $customerSession;
        $this->messageManager    = $messageManager;
        $this->imageUploader     = $imageUploader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Save Cutomer Image
     *
     * @return PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect          = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $uploader                = get_object_vars($this->getRequest()->getFiles());
        $data['profile_picture'] = $uploader['profile_picture'];
        if (!empty($data['profile_picture']['name']) && !empty($data['profile_picture']['tmp_name'])) {
            $data['image'] = $data['profile_picture']['name'];
            $this->imageUploader->saveFileToTmpDir($data['profile_picture']);
            if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                $profilePicture = $data['image'];
                $customerId     = $this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
                $customer       = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
                $customer->setProfilePicture($profilePicture);
                $customer->save();
                $this->imageUploader->moveFileFromTmp($profilePicture);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Avatar Has Been Updated Successfully');
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
                return $resultRedirect;
            }
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addWarning('No image has been Selected');
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

    }
}
```

In Your

> \Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader.php

```
class ImageUploader
{
    /**
     * Core file storage database
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database
     */
    protected $coreFileStorageDatabase;

    /**
     * Media directory object (writable).
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface
     */
    protected $mediaDirectory;

    /**
     * Uploader factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory
     */
    private $uploaderFactory;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * Base tmp path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseTmpPath;

    /**
     * Base path
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $basePath;

    /**
     * Allowed extensions
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $allowedExtensions;

    /**
     * @var File
     */
    private $io;

    /**
     * ImageUploader constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     * @param string $basePath
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $coreFileStorageDatabase,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $io,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        $baseTmpPath,
        $basePath,
        $allowedExtensions
    ) {
        $this->coreFileStorageDatabase = $coreFileStorageDatabase;
        $this->mediaDirectory          = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->uploaderFactory         = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->storeManager            = $storeManager;
        $this->logger                  = $logger;
        $this->io                      = $io;
        $this->baseTmpPath             = $baseTmpPath;
        $this->basePath                = $basePath;
        $this->allowedExtensions       = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Set base tmp path
     *
     * @param string $baseTmpPath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBaseTmpPath($baseTmpPath)
    {
        $this->baseTmpPath = $baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Set base path
     *
     * @param string $basePath
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setBasePath($basePath)
    {
        $this->basePath = $basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowed extensions
     *
     * @param string[] $allowedExtensions
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setAllowedExtensions($allowedExtensions)
    {
        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base tmp path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBaseTmpPath()
    {
        return $this->baseTmpPath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve base path
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return $this->allowedExtensions;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFilePath($path, $imageName)
    {
        return rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . ltrim($imageName, '/');
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for moving and move it
     *
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function moveFileFromTmp($imageName)
    {
        $baseTmpPath      = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $basePath         = $this->getBasePath();
        $baseImagePath    = $this->getFilePath($basePath, $imageName);
        $baseTmpImagePath = $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $imageName);
        try {
            $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->copyFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
            $this->mediaDirectory->renameFile(
                $baseTmpImagePath,
                $baseImagePath
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __($e . 'Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
            );
        }

        return $imageName;
    }

    /**
     * Checking file for save and save it to tmp dir
     *
     * @param string $fileId
     *
     * @return string[]
     *
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function saveFileToTmpDir($fileId)
    {
        $baseTmpPath = $this->getBaseTmpPath();
        $directory   = $this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath);
        if ($this->io->checkAndCreateFolder($directory)) {
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $fileId]);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($this->getAllowedExtensions());
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $result = $uploader->save($this->mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($baseTmpPath));
            if (!$result) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('File can not be saved to the destination folder.')
                );
            }
        }
        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path']     = str_replace('\\', '/', $result['path']);
        $result['url']      = $this->storeManager
            ->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ) . $this->getFilePath($baseTmpPath, $result['file']);
        $result['name'] = $result['file'];
        if (isset($result['file'])) {
            try {
                $relativePath = rtrim($baseTmpPath, '/') . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
                $this->coreFileStorageDatabase->saveFile($relativePath);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __($e . 'Something went wrong while saving the file(s).')
                );
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

> For Further Assitance you can contact me

Comment: I have created a module and put your code but when i run the compile commands, getting the below error.

Comment: Class Vendor\Module\Model\ImageUploader does not exist                                                                                     
  Class Butterfly\Imageupload\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because t  
  he 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated  
  ' directory permission is set to write

Comment: Dear you have to change `Vendor/Module` to `Butterfly/Imageupload`

Comment: where ever there is `Vendor/Module` Change this

Comment: I have changed them but still getting this error when I'm going to compile

Comment: send me your module at waqarcui@gmail.com

Comment: Please ignore the message, I have missed to change them in one file. Now, I can compile successfully. Let me check the functionality and let you know. Thanks

Comment: That's Great...

Comment: accept my answer if it worked for you

Comment: I can't see profile picture field in account page. Where can I locate it?

Comment: just above the nav-links

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't able to see anything related to upload an image

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot in question

Comment: you saw that extension? i posted earlier?

Comment: Are you referring this one https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-2-customize-my-account-page-extension.html or the one which you have posted now?

Comment: if u don't mind you send me your extension i will see your extension

Comment: Sure. I will send to your waqarcui@gmail.com

Comment: Sure I will be happy to help you

Comment: Sent the extension to your email. Please check and help. Thanks

Comment: see your mail hope this help you

Comment: Thanks. After installing the updated extension, I can see the the section to upload the image but how can I save the image?

Comment: Is there anything we have to do for that?

Comment: i will add this functionality to your module soon..

Comment: Thanks so much. Looking for your solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100826/discussion-on-answer-by-waqar-ali-magento2-3-how-to-upload-profile-picture-and).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the above code by Kishan, (I can't reply yet as I just registered to magento stackexchange)

It's working as expected on Magento 2.4! But wondering if there's a way to show the profile picture to the admin panel?

I used it as a way to "Upload valid ID" so the admin needs to verify the ID as well.

Cheers